# Linux Wifi High Power Consumption

Tags: wifi, power-management, powertop, fedora

I'm running Fedora 20, kernel 3.15.6 and ath9 driver with an ateros card.

My battery life is very short, on an older debian install I had around 3 to 4 hours, now I'm between 1 and 2 hours.

Powertop shows that the wireless uses about 18 W which is quite a lot.

Any ideas on what to do or look at?